# Need help with DBMS_COMPRESSION.GET_COMPRESSION_RATIO

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, plsql, sqlpackage

I need some help on how to run the `DBMS_COMPRESSION.GET_COMPRESSION_RATIO` package on all the tables of a database to see if is worth the implementation or not.

This is the procedure I'm running alone and I need a way to automatize it so that I don't have to execute it manually table by table.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
 blkcnt_cmp PLS_INTEGER;
 blkcnt_uncmp PLS_INTEGER;
 row_cmp PLS_INTEGER;
 row_uncmp PLS_INTEGER;
 cmp_ratio NUMBER;
 comptype_str VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
 DBMS_COMPRESSION.GET_COMPRESSION_RATIO (
scratchtbsname => 'USERS' ,
ownname => 'OWNER' ,
objname => 'TABLE_NAME' ,
subobjname => NULL ,
comptype => DBMS_COMPRESSION.COMP_ADVANCED,
blkcnt_cmp => blkcnt_cmp,
blkcnt_uncmp => blkcnt_uncmp,
row_cmp => row_cmp,
row_uncmp => row_uncmp,
cmp_ratio => cmp_ratio,
comptype_str => comptype_str,
subset_numrows=> DBMS_COMPRESSION.comp_ratio_minrows,
objtype => DBMS_COMPRESSION.objtype_table
);
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'Number of blocks used by the compressed sample of the object : ' ||
blkcnt_cmp);
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'Number of blocks used by the uncompressed sample of the object : ' ||
blkcnt_uncmp);
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'Number of rows in a block in compressed sample of the object : ' ||
row_cmp);
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'Number of rows in a block in uncompressed sample of the object : ' ||
row_uncmp);
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Estimated Compression Ratio of Sample : ' ||
cmp_ratio);
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'Compression Type : ' ||
comptype_str);
END;
```

Comment: Basic PL/SQL loop.

Comment: (?) and how do i make that loop??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what PL/SQL is for, for writing code to programmatically make calls. Query the dictionary to get your table names, and within a loop, call the procedure. Something like this:

```
DECLARE
 blkcnt_cmp PLS_INTEGER;
 blkcnt_uncmp PLS_INTEGER;
 row_cmp PLS_INTEGER;
 row_uncmp PLS_INTEGER;
 cmp_ratio NUMBER;
 comptype_str VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  FOR rec_table IN (SELECT owner,   -- open an implicit cursor containing table names. Each row will be assigned to the rec_table record variable
                           table_name 
                      FROM dba_tables
                     WHERE [whatever filter you need])
  LOOP -- execute the code within LOOP... END LOOP for each row in the cursor
    DBMS_COMPRESSION.GET_COMPRESSION_RATIO (
       scratchtbsname => 'USERS' ,
       ownname => rec_table.owner, -- binds to the owner col of the rec_table record variable
       objname => rec_table.table_name, -- binds to the table_name col of the rec_table record variable
       . . . [other params] . . .
    );

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(rec_table.owner||'.'||rec_table.table_name||': Number of blocks used by the compressed sample of the object : ' ||blkcnt_cmp);
    . . . [other dbms outputs] . . .
  END LOOP;
END;
```

You probably don't want to use `dbms_output` for this, however. I would recommend inserting the results into a log table you create for this purpose, which you can then query at will later.

Comment: Thanks! Will try it out and share the results

Comment: so i have edited my procedure and now its giving me this error:  ERROR at line 18:
ORA-06550: line 18, column 5:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
'GET_COMPRESSION_RATIO'
ORA-06550: line 18, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: @DanielSoto, you'll have to review all your parameters and ensure you aren't missing any that are required, that you aren't binding any to a value of an imcompatible datatype, not missing any commas, are using named notation and the parameter names are correct, etc..